# Dimension of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Question: Let $T: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ be self-adjoint and compact. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, let
$$
S_\lambda = \overline{\text{Span} \{ v \in \ell^2 \mid Tv = \gamma v \text{ for some } \gamma \le \lambda \}}
$$
Show that $T$ maps $(S_1)^\perp$ to itself. In general, for what $\lambda$ are $S_\lambda$ and $(S_\lambda)^\perp$ finite dimensional and infinite dimensional?

Comments: This certainly involves the spectral theorem, but I'm struggling to put together a solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the spectral theorem can help. Since $T$ is compact and selfadjoint, there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that 
$$
T=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma_n\,P_n,
$$
where $P_n=\langle\cdot,e_n\rangle e_n$ and $\gamma_n\to0$.

If follows that
$$
S_\gamma=\overline{\text{span}\,\left\{ e_n:\ \gamma_n\leq\lambda\right\}}.
$$
Then 
$$
S_\lambda^\perp=\overline{\text{span}\,\left\{e_n:\ \gamma_n>\lambda\right\}}
$$
As $Te_n=\gamma_ne_n\in\text{span}\,\{e_n\}$ for all $n$, we have that $S_\lambda$ and $S_\lambda^\perp$ are invariant for $T$ for all $\gamma\in\mathbb R$.

As for dimensionality, if $\lambda>0$, then $\dim S_\lambda=\infty$ (because either $\ker T$ is infinite-dimensional or there exist infinitely $\gamma_n$ with $\gamma_n<\lambda$) and $S_\lambda^\perp$ is finite dimensional (because there are finite many positive eigenvalues, each finite-dimensional). The opposite happens when $\lambda<0$: in that case, $S_\lambda$ is finite-dimensional and $S_\lambda^\perp$ is infinite-dimensional.

When $\lambda=0$, all possibilities can arise. For example,

- if $T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\,P_n$, then $S_0=\{0\}$ and $S_0^\perp=\ell^2$.
- if $T=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\,P_n$, then $S_0=\ell^2$ and $S_0^\perp=\{0\}$.
- if $T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\,P_{2n}$, then both $S_0$ and $S_0^\perp$ are infinite-dimensional.

Comment: You help me for the second day in a row - many thanks. I believe I only have one question this time... in the very last part, how are we able to specify a sequence $(\gamma_n)$? Does such a decomposition into some compact self-adjoint operator exist for any sequence $(\gamma_n)$ with $\gamma_n \to 0$?

Comment: One has to have some care. Naively, if you take a sequence $(\gamma_n)$ and define $$T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\gamma_n\,P_n,$$ then the $\gamma_n$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $T$. The problem is that the sequence could contain infinite repetitions, and then $T$ would not be compact.

Comment: I see. But the examples you gave are valid since $\gamma_n \to 0$ and there are no infinite repetitiions, correct? Perhaps if $\gamma_n \searrow 0$ monotonically, then $T = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n P_n$ is necessarily compact and self-adjoint?

Comment: Yes and yes. $ $